# Are unpacked struct in packed struct automatically packed?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, packed

Are unpacked struct in packed struct automatically packed by GCC?

In other words, do `__packed__` attribute automatically propagates to nested structures?

That is to say:

```
struct unpackedStruct{
    int16_t field1;
    int32_t field2;
    // etc...
}

struct packedStruct{
    int16_t field1;
    struct unpackedStruct struct1; // <-- Is this struct packed?
    // etc...
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Comment: It better not be - otherwise passing that member to any other code expecting an ordinary `unpackedStruct` will fail miserably.  Anyway, you could test it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Also, doing direct assignment from one to another would not work.

Comment: This should be trivial to check using the compiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the inner structure is not packed. In [this Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/E3Gaqr), we can see that `struct foo` is not packed inside `struct bar`, which has the `packed` attribute; the `struct bar` object created contains three bytes of padding (visible as `.zero   3`) inside its `struct foo` member, between the `struct foo` members `c` and `i`.

[Current documentation for GCC 10.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes) explicitly says the internal layout of a member of a packed structure is not packed (because of the attribute on the outer structure; it could be packed due to its own definition, of course).

(In [older documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type%20Attributes) that said that applying `packed` to a structure is equivalent to applying it to its members, it meant the effect of applying `packed` to the “variable” that is the member, described in [the documentation for variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable%20Attributes). When `packed` is applied to a structure member, it causes the member’s alignment requirement to be one byte. That is, it eliminates padding between previous members and that member, because no padding is needed to make it aligned. It does not alter the representation of the member itself. If that member is an unpacked structure, it remains, internally, an unpacked structure.)

Answer (score 2):

In practice it does not: see https://godbolt.org/z/4YMaz8.  Note the `.zero 2` of padding between the two members of the `unpackedStruct` member.

This situation is explicitly mentioned in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes), with an example almost identical to yours:

> In the following example `struct my_packed_struct`’s members are packed closely together, **but the internal layout of its `s` member is not packed**—to do that, `struct my_unpacked_struct` needs to be packed too.

```
struct my_unpacked_struct
 {
    char c;
    int i;
 };

struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) my_packed_struct
  {
     char c;
     int  i;
     struct my_unpacked_struct s;
  };
```

The basic idea is that every object of a given type should have the same layout, so that code operating on that type will work on every object of that type.  So `packed` has to apply to a *type*, and you can't have some objects of that type packed and others not.

Comment: I think that `bar` and `foo` code has to break anyway, because `&p.struct1` may not be aligned as a `struct my_unpacked_struct` should be. Clang produces “error: taking address of packed member 's' of class or structure
      'my_packed_struct' may result in an unaligned pointer value
      [-Werror,-Waddress-of-packed-member]” while GCC 10.2 is silent.

Comment: Well, let's say it will break worse - on a platform without strict alignment requirements, it would be likely to work.  Or you could imagine applying `__attribute__((aligned(1)))` to `struct unpackedStruct`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: But I'll take that out anyway.

Comment: I would leave it in but mention the alignment issue separately. If a `struct foo` member were truly packed, it could not be used as a `struct foo` at all. But since it is not packed, just misaligned, there are effectively two types, a `struct foo` and a `struct foo __attribute__((__aligned__(1)))`. You can `memcpy` one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

No - packing is not recursive so every member needs to be packed itself.